# How can I render label to the right of the element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am adding a consent checkbox to an existing form.  I am not able to render the label to the right of the checkbox.  What am I doing wrong?

Please note that the check box has created using `$this->addElement(` because the rest of the form was created this way.

I thank you in advance.

```
$this->addElement('checkbox', 'isUserConsent', array(
        'options'   => array(array('placement' => 'APPEND')),
        'label' => 'Plz activate',
        'validators'    => array(
            array('InArray', false, array(
                'hay' => array(1),
                'messages' => 'Please check the consent box'),
           )
        ),
        'decorators'    => array('ViewHelper','Errors','Label'),
 ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to prepend the label, but you can change this by modifying the decorator's 'placement' option:

```
$this->getElement('isUserConsent')->getDecorator('label')->setOption('placement', 'append');
```

**Edit**: I never use this syntax for decorators but it should be something like this:

```
$this->addElement('checkbox', 'isUserConsent', array(
        'options'   => array(array('placement' => 'APPEND')),
        'label' => 'Plz activate',
        'validators'    => array(
            array('InArray', false, array(
                'hay' => array(1),
                'messages' => 'Please check the consent box'),
           )
        ),
        'decorators'    => array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            'Label' => array(
                'placement' => 'append'
            )
         ),
 ));
```

Comment: I'll try this.  But is there a way to set this up in inside the addElement method?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example of that. Untested though, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I had to do 'decorators' =>array( array('Label', array('placement' => 'APPEND')));  Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for rendering lable of a form element.

**$this->form->name->renderLabel() ;**